# MOSS2007 Giving Error: Access Denied to all users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Over night our installation of MOSS seemed to have stopped working. For ever user it is asking for credentials. You log in with the credentials and then you get the **Access Denied** error. This is happening for everyone. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. No one but Site collection administrator could login.

My problem was that my masterpage has not been approved.

This article helped me to start with the troubleshooting.

http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/02/troubleshooting-access-denied-errors-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Check connectivity between the MOSS server and domain that it's authenticating against.

MOSS Service account being locked out would be one common cause. Also check the IIS config to see if it still sees the domain.

Depends on your authentication configuration as to the specifics.

Comment: We are using NTLM as out authentication method. Wou.d you be able to tell me how to *Check connectivity between the MOSS server and domain that it's authenticating against.* and *heck the IIS config to see if it still sees the domain*

Answer (score 0):

check your SQL Server DB. are you restoring something?

Comment: The backup job looked to have hung but I have killed that.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any events in the logs on the SQL server or any front end web servers? Have you been able to restart any servers in the farm

Answer (score 0):

I dont remember, but I think that:

Also you can check user permissions on MOSS site-collection:

http://MOSS/_layouts/user.aspx - does you have Domain Users or Authenticated users read permissions there? In default configuration all MOSS permissions inherited from that place.